# How Do I Inspect the XML sent from OpenX?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, openx

I'm trying to get Flex and OpenX working together. I can get the ads to work when I view the site on a Mac using Firefox or Safari. But, if I use a PC with IE, I get error #1090 which is an XML parser failure.

Apparently, there is malformed XML. How do I check the XML that OpenX produces? What's the best way to find the nasty node?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: how do you get the XML from openX? is it via an httpService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OpenX talks over HTTP, I highly recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) or [another HTTP debugging proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows) for debugging communications.

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thank you for the recommendation. I appreciate it. 

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

You might also try downloading the beta of Flex 4 which includes a Network Monitor - http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2009.06.01.html

=Ryan 
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Thank you for the reply. The new features in Flex 4 look very useful. They should make life much easier. 

But, I'm going to hold off on upgrading until I've got my project finished. 

-Laxmidi

Comment: You can use the new tool with the 3.4 framework so you don't have to completely change your project. But you are still using a beta tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the data and dump the information.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the message. Wireshark looks very powerful, but with a bit of a learning curve. 

I went with ServiceCapture because it is built for RIA developers, it runs on a mac, and the GUI is simple. http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/

I really appreciate the fact that you took time to help me. Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

I went with ServiceCapture  http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/.

It's pretty simple to use.

-Laxmidi